# Logstash: got one logfile with different logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I've got a logfile from my company with different logs. So the exact problem is that I have regular expressions or patterns which describe the mixed logs! But the logs have at all the same information in a other order. Now the question is how can i distinguish between the different logs?

1. Example:

   `115.123.47.28 - - 24/Feb/2016:00:00:00 -0800 GET /path1/path2/path3/?ex=juDySw3QsKltRRmaFI%253D id=123456 produced=2016`

   My regular Expression:

   `%{IP:userIP}.*- %{GREEDYDATA:logDATE}(?![0-9]) -%{GREEDYDATA:nummer} %{WORD:method} (?:%{UNIXPATH:PATH}).*ex=%{GREEDYDATA:EX} id=%{NUMBER:id} produced=%{NUMBER:production year}`
2. Example:

   `117.143.35.19 - - 24/Feb/2016:00:00:00 -0800 GET /path1/path2/path3/? id=123456 produced=2016 ex=juDySw3QsKltRRmaFI%253D`

   My regular Expression:

   `%{IP:userIP}.*- %{GREEDYDATA:logDATE}(?![0-9]) -%{GREEDYDATA:nummer} %{WORD:method} (?:%{UNIXPATH:PATH}).* id=%{NUMBER:id} produced=%{NUMBER:production year} ex=%{GREEDYDATA:EX}`

So my problem is that the order changed!! My idea was that i define some types but it doesn't work.

```
grok { 
    match => { "message" => ["TYPE1,%{IP:userIP}.*- ......",
                             "TYPE2,%{IP:userIP}.*- ......",
         }
  }

date {
  match => ["logDATE", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

I hope you can help me, so that I can use the information in Kibana afterwards.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples you've given, I would pull the common stuff off the front of each line (up to the "?") and then run the rest through the kv{} filter.

Comment: Can you provide the solution in detail on how we can achieve this using kv filter. Providing the solution in form of configuration file will be easier to understand.

Comment: If you have a string containing key/values (e.g. "a=1 b=2 c=3"), you can pass it to the kv{} filter and it will make fields for you ("a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3).  The kv{} filter has a lot of options to specify delimiters, etc.

Comment: Can you post the Logstash configuration file mentioning grok and kv filter?

Comment: No, I'd rather not do all your work for you.  If you're stuck with a piece of it, open a new question.